# Why app.component.html doesn't recognize server-element, the content of the server-element is not displayed in the browser?

Tags: angular

```html
<app-coockpit (serverCreated)="onServerAdded($event)" 
                (blueprintCreated)="onBluePrintAdded($event)">
  </app-coockpit>`

    <hr>
  <app-server-element *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements" 
  [srvElement]="serverElement">
  
  </app-server-element>
  

</div>

<!--server-element-component-->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let element of serverElements">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name }}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    <strong *ngIf="element.type === 'server'" style="color: red">{{ element.content }}</strong>
                    <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
                </p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain better.

Comment: did you import/declare that component?

Comment: yes I have declare in app.module.ts @eko

Comment: does the `serverElements` array have elements?

Comment: can you provide content of app-server-element

Comment: Yes it has  elements the array serverElements

Comment: <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let element of serverElements">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{ element.name }}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>
                    <strong *ngIf="element.type === 'server'" style="color: red">{{ element.content }}</strong>
                    <em *ngIf="element.type === 'blueprint'">{{ element.content }}</em>
                </p>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>